# C chars add themselves up for no reason

Tags: c, char, printf

I think I'm going insane because I cannot find an explanation to why C is combining my chars.

I've made you guys a test programm...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char alphabet_big[26] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    char alphabet_small[26] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    printf("%s\n", alphabet_small);
    return 0;
}
```

Results: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZV

Why is C combining alphabet_small and alphabet_big? That's not making sense. And why is there a "V" at the end of the char?

I hope someone can provide me an answer to this "problem".

Best regards.

Comment: Use `char alphabet_big[] = ...` . The complier will correctly allocate an array of size 27.  (not 26)

Comment: Too short by one error... Never forget the `'\0'` required for an *array* to be treated as a *string*. (also the stack grows down, with `ABC...` at the top followed by `abc...`) There being no *nul-terminating* character between the arrays, when you print `abc...` no end-of-string follows `'z'` and `printf` happily continues printing characters until it can print no more...

Comment: Undefined behaviour, since the arrays are not nul terminated, and `printf()` with the `%s` assumes a nul terminated array is passed.      A set of 26 letters plus a nul terminator requires the arrays to be at least 27 characters.    Sadly the standard allows truncation if the supplied array is not long enough to hold the initialiser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep in mind that a *[C String](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm)* is defined as a *null terminated* char array.

Change the declaration and initialization statement here: (for both statements.)

```
char alphabet_big[26] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";//forces compiler to use only 26 char
                                                     //regardless of the count of initializers
                                                     //(leaving no room for NULL terminator)
```

To

```
char alphabet_big[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";//allows compiler to set aside
                 ^^                                 //the proper space, no matter how many initializers
```

The first produces *[undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)* when using with any of the string functions, such as `strcpy`, `strcmp`, and in this case `printf` with the `"%s"` format specifier.

The first produces the following, which is not is not a C string:

```
|A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z|?|?|?|
```

While the 2nd produces the following, which is a C string:

```
|A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z|\0|?|?|
```

Note - The `?` symbols used in above illustration depict memory locations that are not owned by the program, and for which the contents are unknown, or may not even exist. A program attempting to access these locations would be invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: Why the question marks at the end of the strings? You can't even assure that the compiler has allocated any memory in those positions.

Comment: It's still wrong, because those memory locations don't just have unknown contents - you can't even know if they exist.

Comment: A bad illustration can be actively harmful if it makes someone believe something that isn't true.

Comment: I do not claim that they do not exist. I claim that they *might* not exist, and neither you or I can say one way or the other because the applicable standards make no guarantees. In fact the standards leave a lot of flexibility to accommodate strange CPU or memory architectures that aren't normally seen in practice. Anyone coming across such a situation would be misled by your "illustration".

Comment: Its _just_ an illustration

Comment: Yes, a **bad/misleading** illustration. It should be fixed or removed.

Comment: @MarkRansom - I added the following phrase: _..., or may not even exist. A program attempting to access these locations would be invoking undefined behavior._

Answer (score 4):

Normally the library functions expect to find a NUL byte at the end of a string, and the compiler is happy to add it for you automatically *except* you've told it that `alphabet_big` has only 26 bytes, essentially avoiding that extra NUL byte, so it combines with what's next.

Remove the `26` and let the compiler count for you.

Comment: Notice that it's not guaranteed to combine it with anything, it's just what happens in this case with this compiler. Nothing to be relied on here.

Comment: Absolutely: passing a string that's not terminated by a NUL byte to a library function that expects one, is asking for trouble.

Comment: OH. Thanks a lot!